# Blockchain Supply Chain Dapp - TypeError: Cannot read properties

Tags: javascript, typeerror, web3js

i have some issues with that code and i cant find the error there... or what cause this error..

```
139  $('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // to prevent page reload when form is submitted
        prodname = $('#prodname').val();
        username = $('#user').val();
        prodname = prodname + "<br>Registered By: " + username;
        console.log(prodname);
        var today = new Date();
        var thisdate = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(async function(accounts) {
          console.log(accounts)
          var receipt = await contract.methods.newItem(prodname, thisdate).send({
              from: accounts[0],
              gas: 1000000
            })
            .then(receipt => {
              console.log(receipt);

              var msg = "<h5 style='color: #53D769'><b>Item Added Successfully</b></h5><p>Product ID: " + receipt.events.Added.returnValues[0] + "</p>";
              $bottom = "<p style='color: #FECB2E'> You may print the QR Code if required </p>"
              qr.value = receipt.events.Added.returnValues[0];

              $("#alertText").html(msg);
              $("#qrious").show();
              $("#bottomText").html($bottom);
              $(".customalert").show("fast", "linear");
            });
        });
        $("#prodname").val('');

 168     });
```

And This  is hitting every time
[image: Error]

I Tried to Change the "qr.value =" to the bottom lane but there is the same issue.

Here is the console log :)

And here is also the whole php site :

```
<?php
session_start();
$color = "navbar-light orange darken-4";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/fibble.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="ICON" href="images/fibble.png" type="image/ico" />

  <title>Fibble - Add New Products</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 0) {
?>

  <body class="violetgradient">
    <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
    <center>
      <div class="customalert">
        <div class="alertcontent">
          <div id="alertText"> &nbsp </div>
          <img id="qrious">
          <div id="bottomText" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;"> &nbsp </div>
          <button id="closebutton" class="formbtn"> Done </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>

    <div class="bgrolesadd">
      <center>
        <div class="mycardstyle">
          <div class="greyarea">
            <h5> Please fill product details </h5>
            <form id="form1" autocomplete="off">
              <div class="formitem">
                <label type="text" class="formlabel"> Product Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="forminput" id="prodname" required>
                <input type="hidden" class="forminput" id="user" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> required>
              </div>
              <button class="formbtn" id="mansub" type="submit">Register Item</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>


      </center>
    <?php
  } else {
    include 'redirection.php';
    redirect('index.php');
  }
    ?>
    <div class='box'>
      <div class='wave -one'></div>
      <div class='wave -two'></div>
      <div class='wave -three'></div>
    </div>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Web3.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- QR Code Library-->
    <script src="./dist/qrious.js"></script>

    <!-- QR Code Reader -->
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- Web3 Injection -->
    <script>
      // Initialize Web3
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'));
      } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'));
      }

      // Set the Contract
      var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

      $("#manufacturer").on("click", function() {
        $("#districard").hide("fast", "linear");
        $("#manufacturercard").show("fast", "linear");
      });

      $("#distributor").on("click", function() {
        $("#manufacturercard").hide("fast", "linear");
        $("#districard").show("fast", "linear");
      });

      $("#closebutton").on("click", function() {
        $(".customalert").hide("fast", "linear");
      });


      $('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // to prevent page reload when form is submitted
        prodname = $('#prodname').val();
        username = $('#user').val();
        prodname = prodname + "<br>Registered By: " + username;
        console.log(prodname);
        var today = new Date();
        var thisdate = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(async function(accounts) {
          var receipt = await contract.methods.newItem(prodname, thisdate).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 })
          .then(receipt => {
>>> ERROR HERE <<<            console.log(receipt);
              var msg="<h5 style='color: #53D769'><b>Item Added Successfully</b></h5><p>Product ID: "+receipt.events.Added.returnValues[0]+"</p>";
              qr.value = receipt.events.Added.returnValues[0];
              $bottom="<p style='color: #FECB2E'> You may print the QR Code if required </p>"
              $("#alertText").html(msg);
              $("#qrious").show();
              $("#bottomText").html($bottom);
              $(".customalert").show("fast","linear");
          });
          //console.log(receipt);
        });
        $("#prodname").val('');

      });

      $('#form2').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // to prevent page reload when form is submitted
        prodid = $('#prodid').val();
        prodlocation = $('#prodlocation').val();
        console.log(prodid);
        console.log(prodlocation);
        var today = new Date();
        var thisdate = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        var info = "<br><br><b>Date: " + thisdate + "</b><br>Location: " + prodlocation;
        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(async function(accounts) {
          var receipt = await contract.methods.addState(prodid, info).send({
              from: accounts[0],
              gas: 1000000
            })
            .then(receipt => {
              var msg = "Item has been updated ";
              $("#alertText").html(msg);
              $("#qrious").hide();
              $("#bottomText").hide();
              $(".customalert").show("fast", "linear");
            });
        });
        $("#prodid").val('');
        $("#prodlocation").val('');
      });


      function isInputNumber(evt) {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        if (!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))) {
          evt.preventDefault();
        }
      }

      (function() {
        var qr = window.qr = new QRious({
          element: document.getElementById('qrious'),
          size: 200,
          value: '0'
        });


      })();

      function openQRCamera(node) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
          node.value = "";
          qrcode.callback = function(res) {
            if (res instanceof Error) {
              alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the camera's frame and try again.");
            } else {
              node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
              document.getElementById('searchButton').click();
            }
          };
          qrcode.decode(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
      }

      function showAlert(message) {
        $("#alertText").html(message);
        $("#qrious").hide();
        $("#bottomText").hide();
        $(".customalert").show("fast", "linear");
      }

      $("#aboutbtn").on("click", function() {
        showAlert("A Decentralised End to End Logistics Application that stores the whereabouts of product at every freight hub to the Blockchain. At consumer end, customers can easily scan product's QR CODE and get complete information about the provenance of that product hence empowering  consumers to only purchase authentic and quality products.");
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the full Repo from this project is
https://github.com/AnubhavDutta/SupplyChainDAPP_FULL

The issue occures in the addproduct.php

This is the receipt log : [Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAXOQ.png)

Comment: As the error mentioned, receipt.events.Added is undefined. You need to check your `contract.methods.newItem` method. You did a console.log(receipt), you should be able to see this statement is probably wrong -> `receipt.events.Added.returnValues[0]`

Comment: Could you please paste the content of `console.log(receipt)` please?

Comment: I posted all what i  got :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of your call `await contract.methods.newItem(prodname, thisdate).send` seems to return indeed an object formatted like below:

```json
{"events": { /* ... whatever content ... */ }}
```

But you are assuming that it always return a dimension:

```json
{"Added": {"returnValues": [ ... somes values here ... ]}}
```

You need to control your data received if you are receiving correctly the `Added.returnValues` section by doing something like:

```js
.then(receipt => {

    var events = receipt.events;
    var results = (events && events.Added && events.Added.returnValues || []);

    if (!results.length) {
        qr.value = `No results received`;
        return;
    }

    qr.value = results[0];

    // ... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Keep me posted, but I'm pretty sure it's because you need to control the result of the `receipt` object received from your .send() answer.

Comment: Try and Error but if i win i will tell you :]

Comment: Mh did not work

Comment: When you run your app, you have a console.log(receipt), what is the content displayed please?

Comment: added the log toe the post